# SQL Server : Duplicate Primary Key error

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, primary-key

I am using SQL Server Express and importing via the Import Wizard so no code to offer really.

The error is shown here:

> Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
>   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
>
> An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
>   Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CXS'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.cxs'. The duplicate key value is (00, 00, 000000, 2017, 03, 01, 00000000, 0).".

I have since done tests in Excel by filtering by the values given. Only one row comes up. I concatenated the eight columns that represent the primary key and then look for duplicates. None are found. Next, using TextFX tools in Notepad ++, I tried to remove duplicates and none were found.

Any other methods for finding this seemingly nonexistent duplicate?

Comment: How about the records that already exist in the database?  When you're trying to import primary key that has existed in the table, you will get the error.

Comment: Prior to every import error, I delete all records using delete from dbo.XXX. Is that sufficient or do I need to go further?

Comment: Hi, Tim, it looks like PK_CXS is a composite primary key with multiple stuff there, are you checking all of them together? Also check if the key has been autogenerated. p.s. a huge composite primary doesn't look good to me here, maybe switch primary key to a identity column make life easier?

Comment: Just to make sure, try to drop and re-create the table.  If it still generates the error, then you know the duplicate is in the file.

Comment: If it is of any value, there are 394,910 in the flat file that I am importing. The import stops at 393,192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions (that are not really a full answer, but with the given data, is as far as I can go).

In some occasions, you may have data as text (such as 1.000000001 and 1.000000002) that are *different* in your text files, but become *the same* once converted into their destination types, because of truncation, rounding, or other kind of conversion effect. This might be the reason why you cannot find duplicates in your text file, yet the database finds them.

There are few techniques you could use and check:

1. Apart from the imported data ... is there any previous data *already* on the target table? If so, there you have a possible source for duplicates.
2. Do you have any way to import "row by row" (or in batches) so that this can help you locate the offending one?

If none of the previous alternatives are possible, you can follow this process:

- Create a table with the same structure as your *target* one, but *without* any `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraints. Let's call it `load_table`
- Import your data to this table. It should not complaint of `PRIMARY KEY` constraints because there isn't any.
- Perform the following query to find out duplicates:

  ```
  SELECT 
      k1, k2, k3 ... kn 
  FROM 
      load_table
  GROUP BY
      k1, k2, k3 ... kn
  HAVING
      count(*) > 1
  ```

  where `k1`, `k2`, `k3` ... `kn` are all the columns that would comprise the primary key of your *target* table.

Using these techniques, you will find the duplicates that SQL Server finds but elude the methods you've used up-until-now.

Comment: I am going to try import rows 1 to 393,190 and see if that works. The import stops at 393,192 of 394,910

Comment: I used your suggestion. The original data source has 27 columns and a duplicate across all 27 columns is virtually impossible. So, cut it off at 8 columns (the primary keys) and then created load table with no primary keys. This was successful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to have helped.