# duplicate primary key sql

Tags: sql, duplicates, primary-key, sql-server-express

This will seem to be a duplicate of 
[SQL Server : Duplicate Primary Key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112009/sql-server-duplicate-primary-key-error).

I will give some background. First, I am using SQL Express. Second, I am using the import and export wizard. Third, the source file is a text file. Fourth, I have successfully imported two other iterations of this file, FIRMS. 2017q2 and 2013q2 imported fine but 2013q1 will not. The reason is a duplicate primary key error.

My primary keys are `state`, `account`, `unit`, and `yrqtr`. There are 25 other foreign keys. Sample data is below.

The error message produces an offending value, so to speak. I find that value in excel and in notepad ++. However, when I dig I find that the combination of those four only happens once.

As a further test, In excel I concatenate the four primary key values into one field and then search for duplicates in the concatenated (combined) value. Excel turns up results but when you look at them, they are not the same. The unit number differs in each item considered a duplicate. I notice that when `name1` (not a primary key) has more than 1 value, excel (and SQL I presume) consider it a duplicate. I am only using excel as a tool to find the duplicates.

```
state   area    account    unit     yrqtr     name1     name2
  32   000001    12345    00001     201301    bakery    xyz bakery
  32   000003    12346    00001     201301    auto      xyz auto
```

As for SQL, I imported 201301 as a load table of sorts instead of appending it to FIRMS. From there, I used the following code. It turns up no results. Lastly, I have looked at 201702 and 201302 and found no duplicates

```
select state,account,unit,yrqtr
from dbo.201301
Group by state,account,unit,yrqtr
having count(*) >1
```

So any ideas as to how I solve this issue of seemingly nonexistent duplicates?

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` definition of the table you're importing data into?

Comment: "In excel I concatenate the four primary key values into one field" - those values listed are not primary-key values themselves because they are not individually unique. Are you saying they're a Composite Key instead? Note that even then, the data you posted doesn't look that unique.

Comment: Finally, are you certain the table is empty when you're importing data? If you're looking at the input files separately then you probably won't see any duplicates, but what about duplicates when compared to data already in the table?

Comment: @Dai, Yes, it is a composite key but when the four values are put into one string, there was no duplication. The issue was that the import wizard was telling me that no data was transferred due to the error. However, it was. Every time that I would try again, it would transfer a trace amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an empty copy of the destination table, disable the primary and foreign keys, import all the files into that table and run a query to check for duplicated data. That might reveal if the data is being modified during import.

```
SELECT state, account, unit, yrqtr, COUNT(*) AS dups 
FROM TableCopy 
GROUP BY state, account, unit, yrqtr 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I performed the steps given above and the issue was that while the error was saying that no data was transferred from 201301 into FIRMS, it was importing trace amounts (18 records of 74103). Thanks for the help.